# Could a simple C program mimic the default 'xxd' command such that its diff'd output would return 0?

Tags: c, hex, diff, hexdump, xxd

I'm trying to write a C executable that will yield identical output to that of a default `xxd` command. For example, lets say I have a  fairly small text file named `test.txt` and an executable named `myxxd`

So, I first make a benchmark for comparison by using:

```
$ touch correct-xxdoutput.txt test-output.txt
$ xxd test.txt > correct-xxdoutput.txt
```

Then using my executable for the same operation but to a different output file:

```
$ ./myxxd test.txt > test-output.txt
$ diff correct-xxdoutput.txt test-output.txt
$
```

I've got pretty close with some guesswork, but my formatting is always wrong somehow, and I don't really understand specifically how `xxd` generates hexDumps. Feels like I just took a totally wrong approach here, but maybe the task is just out of my potential with my current level of C knowledge.

My code (see also: https://pastebin.com/Vjkm8Wb4):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define SIZE 256

//Prototypes
void hexDump(void*, int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //Create and open filestream
    FILE *myfile;
    myfile =fopen(argv[1],"rb");

    for ( ; ; )
    {
        unsigned char buffer[SIZE];
        size_t n = fread(buffer, 1, SIZE, myfile);

        if (n > 0)
            hexDump(buffer, n);
        if (n < SIZE)
            break;
    }

    fclose(myfile);
    return 0;
}


void hexDump (void *addr, int len)
{
    int i;
    unsigned char bufferLine[17];
    unsigned char *pc = (unsigned char*)addr;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if ((i % 16) == 0)
        {
            if (i != 0)
                printf (" %s\n", bufferLine);

            if (pc[i] == 0x00) exit(0);
            printf ("%08x: ", i);
        }

        // Prints Hexcdoes that represent each chars.
        printf ("%02x", pc[i]);
        if ((i % 2) == 1)
            printf (" ");

        if ((pc[i] < 0x20) || (pc[i] > 0x7e))
        {
            bufferLine[i % 16] = '.';
        }

        else
        {
           bufferLine[i % 16] = pc[i];
        }    

        bufferLine[(i % 16) + 1] = '\0'; //Clears the next array buffLine
    }

    while ((i % 16) != 0)
    {
        printf ("  ");
        i++;
    }

    printf ("     %s\n", bufferLine);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible to write a clone of `xxd`.  Whether it is simple depends on your viewpoint; the output from `xxd` has complexities, and its argument handling is non-trivial (and emulating some of the more esoteric options is harder than the core code).  But the basic output is fairly simply managed.

Comment: Also note that you should include the code in the question rather than posting a link to an external site such as PasteBin.  The files at such sites are typically ephemeral; the Q&A on SO are not, and having a question that no longer makes sense because an external site has removed the material is not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a multiple issues with your code, including:

- You don't check that you have a file name to open.
- You don't check that you opened the file that was named.
- You don't have a mechanism to handle the offset into the output, so the addresses at the start of the lines after the first block are wrong.
- Your code tests for a zero byte and exits silently when it encounters one.  This is bad — twice.  Once because a program that is meant to handle binary data must handle zero bytes as well values from 1..255; and once because exiting silently (and claiming success with `exit(0)` to boot) is bad.  You should report the problem (on standard error, not standard output) and exit with an error status — a non-zero status.

The core formatting seems to be mostly OK; there is a problem with padding the short line of data at the end of the file, too.

I came up with this code, which is closely based on yours (but reformatted to suit at least some of my style prejudices — but my style is not far removed from yours most of the time):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 256

void hexDump(size_t, void *, int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    FILE *myfile = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (myfile == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open file '%s' for reading\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    unsigned char buffer[SIZE];
    size_t n;
    size_t offset = 0;
    while ((n = fread(buffer, 1, SIZE, myfile)) > 0)
    {
        hexDump(offset, buffer, n);
        if (n < SIZE)
            break;
        offset += n;
    }

    fclose(myfile);
    return 0;
}

void hexDump(size_t offset, void *addr, int len)
{
    int i;
    unsigned char bufferLine[17];
    unsigned char *pc = (unsigned char *)addr;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if ((i % 16) == 0)
        {
            if (i != 0)
                printf(" %s\n", bufferLine);
            // Bogus test for zero bytes!
            //if (pc[i] == 0x00)
            //    exit(0);
            printf("%08zx: ", offset);
            offset += (i % 16 == 0) ? 16 : i % 16;
        }

        printf("%02x", pc[i]);
        if ((i % 2) == 1)
            printf(" ");

        if ((pc[i] < 0x20) || (pc[i] > 0x7e))
        {
            bufferLine[i % 16] = '.';
        }
        else
        {
            bufferLine[i % 16] = pc[i];
        }

        bufferLine[(i % 16) + 1] = '\0';
    }

    while ((i % 16) != 0)
    {
        printf("  ");
        if (i % 2 == 1)
            putchar(' ');
        i++;
    }
    printf(" %s\n", bufferLine);

}
```

When run on your original source code and compared with the output from the system `xxd`, there are no differences.  I also checked it against a file with just 16 characters (`abcdefghijklmno` plus a newline); the output was the same there too. And I checked it on its own binary — and found and fixed the zero byte and unannounced early exit problem.

Comment: Is "exiting silently" just bad out of a necessary convention for C executables, ie there just isn't a scenario where exiting silently is beneficial? Or is it just akin to a good habit?

Comment: Well, it depends on the context. Consider the `cp` command. It says nothing if it is successful; so a silent exit is fine there. But if something goes wrong, it is crucial that it reports the error (on standard error) identifying what went wrong.  It also returns a non-zero exit code.  Your program abruptly stopped with no indication of why, or that it had chosen to do so.  It was only because I tested it on a third file that I spotted the bug. That would not be satisfactory behaviour. So, a silent exit on error is bad.  A silent exit on success is not.